# I want to auto populate a cell with date when adjacent cell is populated or changed in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, auto-populate

I'm specifically working with Google sheets app on either my tablet or cellphone (though I can access an actual computer and update it through that as well, I mainly work within the apps) and I need to be able to auto-populate the cell in column C with the current date whenever there is data entered or changed. I'm reading all the other answered questions and they're based on excel and I'm not sure it applies to Google Sheets. I'm not very familiar with code or formulas so if you can give me the exact code I need to use and tell me where out needs to be entered I can follow those instructions but just giving me a bunch of code jargon well only serve to confuse me now.

Here's what I'm working on. I have a sheet where all data in Column A is the name of a person, column B is their current weight, and column C is the date they entered their current weight whether it be a new entry or changing an existing entry. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a copy of this sheet: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c1JTGm6vM8ZVaYcIW-JzUjf4CM4hoshKjFWHaKoJDZ8/copy)**

what you are asking is done by a script which runs whenever you enter something in column B

[image: 0]

---

- go to **Tools**
- select **Script editor**

  [image: 0]
- copy paste this script:

---

```
function onEdit(event) { 
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();

  // note: actRng = the cell being updated
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var cindex = actRng.getColumnIndex();

  if (cindex == 2) { // 1 == Column A, 2 == Column B, 3 == Column C, etc.
   var dateCol = sheet.getLastColumn();  
   var lastCell = sheet.getRange(index,dateCol);
   var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MMM-dd-yyyy");
   lastCell.setValue("'" + date);
  }
}
```

- save the project under some name

  [image]
- return to your sheet (you can close script window/tab)

Comment: Okay now my question is how can I add this to an already created spreadsheet with my other sheets with data?

Comment: Okay reading the script what I'm getting from it based on my very limited knowledge of scripting this script you just gave me is saying that if any cell is updated that the date will be auto populated or is it just saying that only if a specific cell is updated then the date will be auto populated? The reason I'm asking this is because I'm wanting for instance to add this script to an existing spreadsheet and the cells that I'm going to be updating is column E except for the first row which contains the title of that column and the column I need auto populated is F except for the first row.

Comment: it works based on columns and what script says is that if column 2 is edited column 3 will receive the date. for E-F columns you need to change `if (cindex == 2)` to `if (cindex == 5)` and for a first row you just need to delete date and type in what you want instead of that date.

Comment: Okay what if there are multiple sheets in the file? Do I need to put the name of the sheet in there somewhere? I only want this sheet that is named "Juvenile weights" to run this script. So I guess I am asking if I need to refer to just this sheet or will it automatically know because I am creating this script from this particular sheet anyway?

Comment: yes, you will need to replace `event.source.getActiveSheet()` with something like "getsheetbyname" (I do not know the correct syntax for that, sry. scripts aren't my domain of expertise)